# How can i get all Changelists of a branch since a specific Changelist?

Tags: java, perforce

I like to use the Perforce Java API to make a list of all changelists since a specific Changelist of a Branch.
On the command line you can get it with: p4 changes -L BRANCHNAME@CHANGELISTID,#head.
But now i like to use the API.

```
 List<IFileSpec> fileSpecs = new ArrayList<>();
 FilePath path = new FilePath(PathType.DEPOT, p4Branch + "/...");
 FileSpec fileSpec = new FileSpec(path);
 fileSpec.setChangelistId(changelist.getId());
 printFileSpec(fileSpec);
 fileSpecs.add(fileSpec);

 try {
     changelists = server.getChangelists(100, fileSpecs, null, null, false, true, false, true);
      if(changelists.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println("Empty Changelists");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Changelists has " + changelists.size() + " elements");
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

With fileSpec.setChangelistId(changelist.getId()); I only can set that it will give me the Changelists before the Changelist (Which is similar to the command: p4 changes -L BRANCHNAME@CHANGELISTID  that's also exact how my fileSpecs looks.

Is there a possibility to set something in the API to achieve this? 
Or do i have to use some different Methods of the API?

Thanks.

Comment: To clarify: you want to use the Java API to construct a FileSpec with the revision specifier "@CHANGELISTID,#head", but so far all you've been able to do is to set the revision specifier to "@CHANGELISTID". Correct?

Comment: yes. 
I think I explained it a little bit more difficult :D
But thats what i like to have.

Answer (score 0):

Try building your FileSpecs this way:

```
List<IFileSpec> fileSpecs = FileSpecBuilder.makeFileSpecList(p4Branch + "/...@" + changelist.getId() + ",#head");
```