# Get List of changelist after a particular changelist using Perforce java API

Tags: java, perforce

Using Perforce Java API ,

Is there a way get list of changelists after a particular changelist for a particular branch?

I have gone through this link
[How can i get all Changelists of a branch since a specific Changelist?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30534297/how-can-i-get-all-changelists-of-a-branch-since-a-specific-changelist)

Comment: And how is your question different from the question that you linked to?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want the submitted changelists. This will work:

```
p4 changes -l -s submitted <branch_path>/...@particular_changeslist#,now
```

For example, to see the files on the "Release" branch since changeslist 1234:

```
p4 changes -l -s submitted //depot/Release/...@1234,now
```

Comment: This is not using the P4Java API, which is what was requested.